# How to parsing simple json in strings c++?

Tags: c++, json

I have a `string` that is containing a small `json` containing only `string`s. I have used `stringstream` and `boost::property_tree::read_json` for reading it. I have seen that this is not very fast, moreover, the boost json parser is not thread safe (because of the streams). So I have tried to make it in another way:

```
std::vector< std::string > fields;
std::vector< std::string > values;
int separator = -1;
int prevSeparator = 0;
int fieldBegin = 0;
int fieldEnd = 0;
int valueBegin = 0;
int valueEnd = 0;

int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
do
{
    prevSeparator = separator + 1;
    separator = jsonStream.substr(prevSeparator, jsonStream.size() - prevSeparator - 1).find_first_of(',') + prevSeparator;

    std::string element = jsonStream.substr(prevSeparator, separator - prevSeparator);

    int fvSeparator = element.find_first_of(':');
    std::string field = element.substr(0, fvSeparator);
    std::string value = element.substr(fvSeparator + 1, element.size() - fvSeparator - 1);

    fieldBegin = field.find_first_of('\"') + 1;
    fieldEnd = field.find_last_of('\"');
    fields.push_back(field.substr(fieldBegin, fieldEnd - fieldBegin));

    valueBegin = value.find_first_of('\"') + 1;
    valueEnd = value.find_last_of('\"');
    values.push_back(value.substr(valueBegin, valueEnd - valueBegin));
} while (prevSeparator - separator <= 0);
```

Do you think it is good enough or what shall I improve?

Comment: When talking about performance, we don't *"think"*. We **measure.** Also, if you are already using a working JSON parser, why roll your own? (no, this isn't any more thread-safe than Boost's one.)

Comment: I could only add: have a look at json++. It is fast enough.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant : How to make it thread safe? Just adding the macro `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE` ?

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your description of the input right, you have a Json-Array containing strings. That means, it starts with `["`, then follows a sequence of strings separated by `","`. Finally you have `"]`.
Here is a high level algorithm for you:

1. Split input by `"`, watching for escaped quotes.
2. Remove strings `[` and `]` from the ends (there can be whitespace in there, too).
3. Remove strings `,` that appear in between the desired strings (there can be whitespace in there, too).
4. Unescape based on Json escaping rules, in case there are any escapes.